# how can i control my children's computer at the other room anonymously (with the same internet modem)?

Tags: parental-control

I have 2 computer with windows 10, but in different rooms with same  internet modem, my children use incognito mode to visit some undesired sites. **how can I control them anonymously and see their screen whenever I want? thank you for your answers.

Comment: More information needed: OS of the computers involved? FOSS? Commercial software OK?

Comment: Block the type of sites on router level. Lists for various types exist.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any anonymous tools to look at the screens.  The normal tools will give a visual indication on the screen that it is being viewed.  But you can use the router to see what urls have been visited.  If your router does not support it, get a decent one, they are not that expensive.  I use Unify ones.

Here are some methods that I have used to mitigate it.

- Install a keylogger, you can see the history of everything that they have typed.  This helps when they are typing on social media platforms as well.
- If your router supports it, block the sites by type or urls
- Use OpenDNS.  In the free mode you can use a category based filtering and a few specific urls.  You need to run a little IP address updater and set the DNS on the router or that PC to their IP address.  No one can then view those sites.  See Image-1
- Use Raspberry Pi and run a PiHole.  You can add specific sites and download lists of urls that you can block.  You need to point the router's DNS to it (or just that PC's DNS).

The last two work by returning invalid urls for the domain names.

You can also install a decent anti-virus/malware program which will allow you to block urls.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable incognito mode in chrome and Firefox. I use Firefox and there is an option to entirely disable incognito by changing the registry or using a json file as described [here](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/disabling-inprivate-browsing-firefox-62470.html). This is fairly difficult for the children to bypass. But for the determined they can access using VPN even if you block at DNS level. The best option is to allow children to only use the system in the hall or where they have the fear of anyone watching them.

You can have a similar approach with [Google chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3388080?hl=en&msgid=91027228)